# One corner piece orientation problem - Rubik's Cube

Tags: rubiks-cube

[image]!

I have been trying to solve Rubik's cube using beginner's method provided here: https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/how-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube-beginners-method/

I ended up with just one last corner which is not oriented properly as shown in the picture. I cannot seem to solve it using R’ D’ R D algorithm, it messes up the whole square when the corner piece gets oriented. Every time I try to solve the cube, it again has just one last corner disoriented. None of the algorithms mention one last corner case. They always talk about 2 or more corners disoriented. I don't understand. Can someone explain what's happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Weather Vane is indeed right, there can never be a single piece incorrect on a regular 3x3x3 Cube. You must have accidentally twist it in one of your solves. Simply twist it back, and then you should be able to scramble/solve it normally again. If it happens again later, maybe your cube is a bit too loose causing this to happen in the heat of a solve. In that case try tightening the screws a tiny bit to reduce this from happening again.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the piece at the opposite corner has a similar misorientation, the cube has been tampered with.

There can never be a single piece wrong. A set of moves to twist one piece, always has a corresponding side-effect.